# When canning strawberry preserves can you substitute lime juice for lemon juice?

Tags: canning, strawberries, lime

I am making strawberry margarita preserves and would like to substitute lime juice for lemon juice..  Would that present a problem once I can them?

Answer (score 2):

No it won't be a problem.

For *safe canning*, time, temperature and sufficient acidity are the relevant variables. Neither is affected by your substitution.

*Taste-wise* switching from lemon to lime will change the results, but obviously that is exactly your goal. (Nice idea, that "Strawberry Margarita preserve" btw.)

Comment: +1, but maybe we should note a difference between lemons and limes.  Limes have a much stronger delayed bitterness when compared to lemons.  So after a day or two the recipe made with limes will develop a bitter taste (LARL turning into limonin,) that needs to be compensated for with salt, extra sugar, or some other flavor trick.

Comment: @papin For juice as well? OP is not planning to use pulp or peels.

Comment: Your right that the LARL is not uniformly distributed among the fruit, but there is enough in the juice sacks (the parts of the segments) to bitter the squeezed juice.  Lemon and lime to me feel like Valencia and Navel oranges.  Love Navels, but their juice goes bitter too fast.

Comment: @papin Wouldn't the sugar in a preserve be enough?

Comment: I'm sure it could be enough.  A recipe made for lemons made need a bit of adjusting if made with limes.